# How to return related object, in Angular 2 with TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

Sorry, i'm new in TypeScrit and Angular 2, and sorry for my poor english, it is not my native language. But i need your help.

I have this data model:

### country.ts

```
export class Country{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

### state.ts

```
export class State{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    country_id: number
}
```

### city.ts

```
export class City{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    state_id: number
}
```

I have many Countries, related with some states and these related with some cities, for example : EEUU -> Florida -> Orlando

The user select first one country, in the next step, must be select one state related with this country and the last step select one city related with this state.

The goal is complete a `<select></select>` tag with this data, but i can't create a method to return the data.

I tried this, but i have this error "Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise'" in method "getCitiesRefState" it's something similar to "getCity()", but this work fine.

My code is:

### mock-data.ts

```
import { Country } from './country';
import { State } from './state';
import { City } from './city';

export const PAIS: Pais[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'EEUU'}
];

export const PROVINCIA: Provincia[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Florida', pais_id: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'Georgia', pais_id: 1},
  {id: 3, name: 'Alabama', pais_id: 1}
];

export const LOCALIDAD: Localidad[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Orlando', provincia_id: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'Tampa', provincia_id: 1},
  {id: 3, name: 'Gainesvielle', provincia_id: 1}
];
```

### city.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { City } from './city';
import { CITY } from './mock-data';
@Injectable()
export class CityService{
    getCities(): Promise<City[]> {
        return Promise.resolve(CITY);
    }
    getCitiesRefState(id: number): Promise<City[]> {
        return this.getCities().then(cities=> cities.find(city => city.state_id === id));
    }
    getCity(id: number): Promise<City> {
        return this.getCities()
        .then(cities => cities.find(city=> city.id === id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getCitiesRefState` method is declared to return a `Promise<City[]>` but actually returns a `Promise<City>`. It helps to see if we expand the method out.

```
getCitiesRefState(id: number): Promise<City[]> {
    return this.getCities()
        .then(cities=> {
            // cities.find() will return a City, not a City[]
            return cities.find(city => city.state_id === id)
        });
}
```

As far as your `<select>` you will need to give more code to show what is going on there.

Comment: I tried your solution, but i have the same error. I understand the error, but i don't know how to resolve it!